# AWS Global Tables not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Created a table under us-east-1 and enabled global table on us-west-2.

Inserted 43 items in us-east-1.

When I scan all the items in **us-east-1**, it shows,

```
  "ScannedCount": 43, 
  "ConsumedCapacity": null
```

When I scan on **us-west-2**, waited for 30 minutes, results are still the same.

```
 "ScannedCount": 3, 
 "ConsumedCapacity": null
```

What am I missing here?

Read and Write Capacity is 5/5 on all regions. There are not too many records for it to replicate.

**Update from AWS Support:**

AWS Support was not able to find the root cause of the problem. Had to delete the table and recreate it. It worked from there.

Comment: So you are saying 3 of 43 actually did replicate?

Comment: Yes. 3 were replicated and 40 did not.